# Get Excel metadata

Tags: excel, powershell, metadata, vba

I'm using [this PowerShell script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/10/09/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-read-microsoft-excel-metadata/) that shows how to get the Excel file metadata:

```bsh
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\excel.xls")
$binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]
foreach ($property in $workbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties) {
    $pn = [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("name", $binding::GetProperty, $null, $property, $null)
    trap [System.Exception] {
        Write-Host -Foreground blue "Value not found for $pn"
        continue
    }
    "$pn`: " + [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("value", $binding::GetProperty, $null, $property, $null)
}
$excel.Quit()
```

Can someone please assist:

1. For the script line:

   ```bsh
   [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("name", $binding::GetProperty, $null, $property, $null)
   ```

   The way I understand this `[System.__ComObject]` represents the "type" of the returned object in the `foreach` loop.

   Can you please explain why

   ```bsh
   [System.__ComObject]$property.InvokeMember("name", $binding::GetProperty, $null, $property, $null)
   ```

   causes the "trap" to be triggered? Is not the "object" being returned in the `foreach` loop, `$property`?
2. Also, I have found [this Excel VBA code](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/last_modified.php) to get the "Last Save Time":

   ```vb
   Function LastModified() as Date
       LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
   End Function
   ```

   This code works in Excel VBA. So why does this equivalent PowerShell code not work:

   ```bsh
   $lst = $workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
   [System.__ComObject]$lst.InvokeMember("value", $binding::GetProperty, $null, $property, $null)
   ```

Comment: Do you have Excel installed? Does this work for you in VBA?

Comment: The code from the first linke works just fine for me. Must be your environment.

Comment: The article from where you got the code already explains what `[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember()` does and why it's used. What is unclear about that explanation?

Comment: Thanks. Apparently "[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember()" this is how the InvokeMember function is called. This is the reference: [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy(v=vs.110).aspx. There is this example there `code`typeof(C).InvokeMember("F", BindingFlags.SetField, null, c, new Object[] {1, "b"}, null, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

1. From [about_Trap documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_trap?view=powershell-5.1):

> When a terminating error occurs that is not handled in another way in
>   a script or command, Windows PowerShell checks for a Trap statement
>   that handles the error. If a Trap statement is present, Windows
>   PowerShell continues running the script or command in the Trap
>   statement.

2. Your code logic here differs from what's inside the `foreach` loop. The first line is also different from the VBA example but that part should be working fine.

---

```
$lst = $excel.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last save time") # like in VBA
$lst = $workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")             # also fine

[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("value", $binding::GetProperty, $null, $lst, $null)
```